# Splitting a pandas Data frame column depending if word is capital or not

Tags: regex, pandas

I have a data frame column in the below format:

| header |
| --- |
| THIS IS an example |
| ALSO this |
| ONE LAST |
| J. one more |

I want to split it into two columns:

| header1 | header2 |
| --- | --- |
| THIS IS | an example |
| ALSO | this |
| ONE LAST | null |
| null | J. one more |

I have tried extracting the information like this:

```
df1['header'].str.split('[A-Z]', expand=True)
```

but my regular expressions are not up to par.  Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Greek Letter Notice**

To only match Greek uppercase letters, replace `[A-Z]` in below patterns with `[\u0391-\u03A1\u03A3-\u03A9]`. To match both ASCII and Greek uppercase letters use `[a-zA-Z\u0391-\u03A1\u03A3-\u03A9]`.

I.e.

```py
rx = r'^\s*(?P<header1>(?:[\u0391-\u03A1\u03A3-\u03A9]+\b(?!\.)(?:\s+[\u0391-\u03A1\u03A3-\u03A9]+)*\b)?)(?:\s+(?P<header2>.*))?'
new_df = df['header'].str.extract(rx, expand=True)
```

### See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fMbh8k/1).

You can use

```py
df[['header1', 'header2']] = df['header'].str.extract(r'^\s*((?:[A-Z]+\b(?!\.)(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*)?)\s*(.*)', expand=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
               header   header1      header2
0  THIS IS an example   THIS IS   an example
1           ALSO this      ALSO         this
2            ONE LAST  ONE LAST             
3         J. one more            J. one more
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hjENIN/2).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `((?:[A-Z]+\b(?!\.)(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*)?)` - Group 1 (`header1`): an optional sequence of one or more uppercase ASCII letters (not followed with a `.` char) and then zero or more sequences of one or more whitespaces and one or more uppercase ASCII letters
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*)` - Group 2 (`header2`): any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible.

You may extract to a new dataframe using named capturing groups:

```py
>>> new_df = df['header'].str.extract(r'^\s*(?P<header1>(?:[A-Z]+\b(?!\.)(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*)?)\s*(?P<header2>.*)', expand=True)
>>> new_df
    header1      header2
0   THIS IS   an example
1      ALSO         this
2  ONE LAST             
3            J. one more
```

Comment: When I run your example it works fine, but on my data frame it does not, although I cover all the cases. It returns two empty columns. Could it be because of the encoding? My data set is utf8 and you mention ascii. Or should I be looking somewhere else for the root of the problem? Again thanks for your help.

Comment: @PeterGould `[A-Z]` matches only ASCII uppercase letters. It does not match `Ф`, for example. It does not matter if you use ASCII  or UTF8 to encode the file, it is not about that. If you get empty columns you did not share the data you have with us. We can only test on what you shared.

Comment: @PeterGould [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70345730/splitting-a-pandas-data-frame-column-depending-if-word-is-capital-or-not/70345767?noredirect=1#comment124351153_70345840), you show Greek uppercase letters. Do you need to support Greek?

Comment: Yes I do need to support greek

Comment: @PeterGould I added a note on top of the answer.

Comment: One last thing, and sorry for this I run the code  ```new_df = df1['header'].str.extract(r'^\s*(?P<header1>(?:[\u0391-\u03A1\u03A3-\u03A9]+\b(?!\.)(?:\s+[\u0391-\u03A1\u03A3-\u03A9]+)*)?)\s*(?P<header2>.*)', expand=True)``` but I get the first capital letter of the next word which is capital then lowercase too.

Comment: @PeterGould Use `r'^\s*(?P<header1>(?:[\u0391-\u03A1\u03A3-\u03A9]+\b(?!\.)(?:\s+[\u0391-\u03A1\u03A3-\u03A9]+)*\b)?)(?:\s+(?P<header2>.*))?'`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use 2 named capture groups, and join the columns.

```
^(?P<header1>[A-Z]+(?:[^\S\n]+[A-Z]+)*)?(?:(?:^|[^\S\n]+)(?P<header2>.+))?$
```

(or use `[a-z].*` instead of `.+` if it must start with a lowercase char)

- `^` Start of string
- `(?P<header1>[A-Z]+` Capture group *header1*, match 1+ chars A-Z
- `(?:[^\S\n]+[A-Z]+)*)?` Optionally match spaces and 1+ chars A-Z
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?:^|[^\S\n]+)` Either assert the start of the string or match 1+ spaces
  - `(?P<header2>.+)` Named group *header2* match 1+ chars
- `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3X78SS/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ESqvEC).

Example

```
import pandas as pd

strings = [
    "THIS IS an example",
    "ALSO this",
    "ONE LAST",
    "J. one more"
]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(strings, columns=["header"])
df1 = df1.join(
    df1['header'].str.extract(
        '^(?P<header1>[A-Z]+(?:[^\S\n]+[A-Z]+)*)?(?:(?:^|[^\S\n]+)(?P<header2>.+))?$',
        expand=True
    )
    .fillna('')
)

print(df1)
```

Output

```
               header   header1      header2
0  THIS IS an example   THIS IS   an example
1           ALSO this      ALSO         this
2            ONE LAST  ONE LAST             
3         J. one more            J. one more
```

Comment: I get the bellow error here ```ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['area_lvl_2', 'area_lvl_1'], dtype='object')```

Comment: @PeterGould I can not reproduce that, I get this output https://ideone.com/Jqptim Are you using the same column names?

Comment: Yes I changed the column names and now it is running. but not populating the columns header1 and header2. This is what I get |header|header1|header2|
|--------|-----------|----------|
|ΓΙΑΝΝΙΤΣΩΝ  |null  |null|
|ΕΛΕΥΘΕΡΙΟ Άγιος Γεώργιος|  null  |null|
|ΕΛΕΥΘΕΡΙΟ  |null  |null|
|ΕΛΕΥΘΕΡΙΟ  |null  |null|

Comment: @PeterGould You have updated the question, and for that I have updated my answer. I have added an example to show that for the given data it works. I can not reproduce the outcome from your comments. What you could do is update the question with the code that is not working for you, so that you might get an answer where the code is working.

Answer (score 1):

Using `str.extract` we can try:

```py
df["header1"] = df["header"].str.extract(r'^([A-Z]+(?: [A-Z]+)?)')
df["header2"] = df["header"].str.extract(r'\b([a-z]+(?: [a-z]+)?)')
```